# Create multiple aurora clusters using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-aurora

Is there a Terraform way to create multiple Aurora DB clusters? I tried to make the cluster_name a list but looks like the "cluster_identifier" resource expects a String and not a list of strings. I can create multiple instances for a cluster but I don't see a way to create multiple DB clusters in Terraform.

```
# The Aurora cluster (which contains database instances created below).
  resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora_cluster" {
  engine                          = var.rds_engine
  engine_version                  = var.rds_engine_version
  cluster_identifier              = var.rds_cluster_name
  master_username                 = local.aurora_creds.username
  master_password                 = local.aurora_creds.password
  db_subnet_group_name            = var.subnet_group_name
  iam_roles                       = var.rds_iam_roles
  vpc_security_group_ids          = var.security_groups
   lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
}
```

}

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "aurora_instance" {
engine                  = var.rds_engine
engine_version          = var.rds_engine_version
count                   = var.instance_count
identifier              = "${var.rds_cluster_name}-${count.index}"
cluster_identifier      = var.rds_cluster_name
instance_class          = var.rds_instance_class
db_subnet_group_name    = var.subnet_group_name
availability_zone       = lookup(element(var.subnet_zones, count.index), "zone")
publicly_accessible     = false
lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a [mcve] of what you've tried? If it errors in some way then it would also be useful to include the error output. If it doesn't do what you want then it would be good to clearly explain what your existing code does compared to what you'd want it to do.

Comment: I added code. My goal is to be able to create multiple "aws_rds_cluster" resources.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to provision `x` amount of a resource in Terraform.

You can use the [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count) attribute in the resource itself.

```
locals {
  instance_count = 2
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "aurora_instance" {
  count                   = local.instance_count
  engine                  = var.rds_engine
  engine_version          = var.rds_engine_version
  identifier              = "${var.rds_cluster_name}-${count.index}"
  cluster_identifier      = var.rds_cluster_name
  instance_class          = var.rds_instance_class
  db_subnet_group_name    = var.subnet_group_name
  availability_zone       = lookup(element(var.subnet_zones, count.index), "zone")
  publicly_accessible     = false
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Or you can use the [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) attribute.

```
locals {
  zones = ["us-west-2a", "us-west-2b"]
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "aurora_instance" {
  for_each                = toset(local.zones)
  engine                  = var.rds_engine
  engine_version          = var.rds_engine_version
  identifier              = "${var.rds_cluster_name}-${each.key}"
  cluster_identifier      = var.rds_cluster_name
  instance_class          = var.rds_instance_class
  db_subnet_group_name    = var.subnet_group_name
  availability_zone       = each.key
  publicly_accessible     = false
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Comment: I am already able to create multiple instances. I want to create multiple Aurora clusters. Each cluster will have multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a module for this and then use the approach of 1efty with foreach our count, internally this module will create the instances for you: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/rds-aurora/aws

For example:

```
module "cluster" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/rds-aurora/aws"

  for_each = {
    cluster_one = "a"
    cluster_two = "b"
  } 
  name           = "test-aurora-db-postgres96"
  engine         = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version = "14.5"
  instance_class = "db.r6g.large"
  instances = {
    one = {}
    2 = {
      instance_class = "db.r6g.2xlarge"
    }
  }

  vpc_id               = "vpc-12345678"
  db_subnet_group_name = "db-subnet-group"
  security_group_rules = {
    ex1_ingress = {
      cidr_blocks = ["10.20.0.0/20"]
    }
    ex1_ingress = {
      source_security_group_id = "sg-12345678"
    }
  }

  storage_encrypted   = true
  apply_immediately   = true
  monitoring_interval = 10

  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = ["postgresql"]

  tags = {
    Environment = "dev"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}
```